# Same problem solved with linearity of expectation and Hypergeometric distribution. Need explanation...

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the problem:
There is population of size S. Select two independent samples A and B. A size = n
B size = m. What is the expected overlap between A and B? 
$E$[overlap between $A$ and $B$] $=$ $E$[# of people both in $A$ and $B$]

Solution:
$E[X] = S$ * $P$(person $i$ is in $A$ and $B$)

P(Person i is in A and B) = P(Person i is in A) \times P(Person i is in B)
$$E[X] = S * (\frac{n}{S})(\frac{m}{S})$$

Professor claimed that there is another solution that uses Hypergeometric distribution:
$$\frac{{n}\choose{i}}{{S}\choose{m}} \times \frac{{S-n}\choose{m-i}}{{S}\choose{m}}$$

I do not understand how they are interrelated and how this holds:
$$\frac{{n}\choose{i}}{{S}\choose{m}} \times \frac{{S-n}\choose{m-i}}{{S}\choose{m}} = S \times (\frac{n}{S})(\frac{m}{S})$$

I am not sure how to get from $LHS$ - $RHS$

Thanks